# Create multiple divs dynamically and assign id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying to create divs dynamically with jquery. I have a function called `createDivs` that takes an array of x names. I would like to create a `div` for each name and assign the `div` the `id=”new-name”` that was passed in through the array. All dynamically created divs are appended to `<div id=”main”></div>`. However so far the divs are created but the names are placed in each div. How could I assign a single name per div and append to `main`?

```
function createDivs (divName) {
          for (var i=0, len=divName.length; i < len; i++) {
        $('#main').append('div').addClass('new-'+divName)
      }
}
```

call the function

```
createDivs(['navBar', 'footer', 'sidePanel', 'socialFeed']);
```

Current output

```
<div id="main">
<div id="new-" navBar,footer,sidePanel,socialFeed=""></div>
<div id="new-" navBar,footer,sidePanel,socialFeed=""></div>
<div id="new-" navBar,footer,sidePanel,socialFeed=""></div>
<div id="new-" navBar,footer,sidePanel,socialFeed=""></div>
</div>
```

Desired output

```
<div id="main">
<div id="navBar"></div> 
<div id="footer"></div> 
<div id="sidePanel"></div>
<div id="socialFeed"></div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
$('#main').append('div').addClass('new-'+divName)
```

To

```
var $div = $("<div>", { id: divName[i] });
$('#main').append($div);
```

Comment: This worked perfect. I see what i was doing wrong now. As mentioned above I was assigning the whole array to the div and just the element.